# PyEphem: ValueError: that satellite seems to stay always below your horizon

Tags: python, angle, elevation, pyephem, satellite

I have a problem with the PyEphem library.

In a few words, I have to compute passes of a satellite based on a TLE for different observers because they have to communicate with. But to be sure they would be able to communicate with the satellite they could specify the min elevation angle they want.

I'm using the guy.horizon to precise which elevation angle I want for a particular observer.

Here is my code

```
def test_ephem_horizon():
str1 = 'SWISSCUBE'
str2 = '1 35932U 09051B   15278.30192626  .00000528  00000-0  13209-3 0  9992'
str3 = '2 35932  98.4206  37.8361 0007688   9.6843 350.4501 14.55537404319986'

#satellite
swisscube = ephem.readtle(str1, str2, str3)

#observer
guy = ephem.Observer()
guy.lon, guy.lat = '18.6107', '53.0217'
guy.date = datetime.datetime.now()
print "datetime.now(): " , guy.date

##################################### FIRST CASE #####################################################
degrees=10
minutes=0
seconds=0

elevation_angle_str = str(degrees) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds)
guy.horizon = elevation_angle_str
swisscube.compute(guy)

passes = []
passes.append(passListToDic(guy.next_pass(swisscube)))

nb_passes = 30
for i in range(0, nb_passes):
    guy.date = passes[i]['set_time'].datetime() + datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=1)
    temp_pass = guy.next_pass(swisscube)
    print 'horizon: ', guy.horizon, '  passe[', i, ']: ', passes[i]
    passes.append(passListToDic(temp_pass))

##################################### SECOND CASE #####################################################
degrees=45
minutes=0
seconds=0

elevation_angle_str = str(degrees) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds)
guy.horizon = elevation_angle_str
swisscube.compute(guy)

passes = []
passes.append(passListToDic(guy.next_pass(swisscube)))
elevation_angle_str = str(degrees) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds)

nb_passes = 30
for i in range(0, nb_passes):
    guy.date = passes[i]['set_time'].datetime() + datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=1)
    temp_pass = guy.next_pass(swisscube)
    print 'horizon: ', guy.horizon, '  passe[', i, ']: ', passes[i]
    passes.append(passListToDic(temp_pass))
return passes

def passListToDic(_pass):
    return {'rise_time': _pass[0], 'rise_azimuth': _pass[1], 'max_alt_time': _pass[2],
                       'max_alt': _pass[3], 'set_time': _pass[4], 'set_azimuth': _pass[5]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_ephem_horizon()
```

Here is the result of the test:

```
datetime.now():  2015/10/6 17:26:14
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 0 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/6 21:27:34, 'max_alt': 11:05:25.5, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/6 21:28:55, 'rise_azimuth': 63:13:09.7, 'set_time': 2015/10/6 21:30:16, 'set_azimuth': 30:12:12.2}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 1 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/6 23:01:06, 'max_alt': 50:50:24.1, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/6 23:05:43, 'rise_azimuth': 142:00:00.4, 'set_time': 2015/10/6 23:10:22, 'set_azimuth': 352:46:19.8}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 2 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/7 00:39:47, 'max_alt': 26:27:07.4, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/7 00:43:48, 'rise_azimuth': 209:21:48.1, 'set_time': 2015/10/7 00:47:52, 'set_azimuth': 324:33:00.2}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 3 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/7 12:32:41, 'max_alt': 51:37:50.4, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/7 12:37:25, 'rise_azimuth': 23:25:50.2, 'set_time': 2015/10/7 12:42:07, 'set_azimuth': 177:08:21.7}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 4 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/7 14:10:56, 'max_alt': 28:06:15.8, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/7 14:15:01, 'rise_azimuth': 357:46:42.2, 'set_time': 2015/10/7 14:19:06, 'set_azimuth': 242:05:31.8}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 5 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/7 22:09:02, 'max_alt': 21:26:22.3, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/7 22:12:37, 'rise_azimuth': 104:56:52.7, 'set_time': 2015/10/7 22:16:14, 'set_azimuth': 7:39:29.7}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 6 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/7 23:45:14, 'max_alt': 72:08:14.0, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/7 23:50:00, 'rise_azimuth': 171:06:17.4, 'set_time': 2015/10/7 23:54:49, 'set_azimuth': 341:24:44.1}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 7 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/8 01:27:02, 'max_alt': 11:38:22.2, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/8 01:28:43, 'rise_azimuth': 255:09:20.2, 'set_time': 2015/10/8 01:30:25, 'set_azimuth': 296:53:48.9}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 8 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/8 11:39:58, 'max_alt': 19:34:40.0, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/8 11:43:29, 'rise_azimuth': 42:56:40.7, 'set_time': 2015/10/8 11:46:58, 'set_azimuth': 136:13:53.0}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 9 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/8 13:16:59, 'max_alt': 70:27:01.0, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/8 13:21:49, 'rise_azimuth': 11:41:28.5, 'set_time': 2015/10/8 13:26:36, 'set_azimuth': 206:26:00.0}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 10 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/8 14:56:14, 'max_alt': 14:37:51.1, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/8 14:58:50, 'rise_azimuth': 342:09:46.7, 'set_time': 2015/10/8 15:01:27, 'set_azimuth': 276:26:32.5}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 11 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/8 22:52:05, 'max_alt': 43:05:25.7, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/8 22:56:35, 'rise_azimuth': 135:49:13.8, 'set_time': 2015/10/8 23:01:08, 'set_azimuth': 355:08:58.4}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 12 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/9 00:30:18, 'max_alt': 31:15:34.8, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/9 00:34:33, 'rise_azimuth': 202:07:27.1, 'set_time': 2015/10/9 00:38:51, 'set_azimuth': 328:02:20.7}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 13 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/9 12:23:35, 'max_alt': 43:14:41.9, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/9 12:28:13, 'rise_azimuth': 26:11:34.5, 'set_time': 2015/10/9 12:32:48, 'set_azimuth': 170:40:22.3}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 14 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/9 14:01:39, 'max_alt': 32:31:47.4, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/9 14:05:56, 'rise_azimuth': 0:22:27.4, 'set_time': 2015/10/9 14:10:13, 'set_azimuth': 235:38:45.9}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 15 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/9 22:00:17, 'max_alt': 18:42:23.0, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/9 22:03:34, 'rise_azimuth': 97:46:38.3, 'set_time': 2015/10/9 22:06:52, 'set_azimuth': 10:50:40.6}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 16 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/9 23:36:01, 'max_alt': 85:20:39.1, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/9 23:40:49, 'rise_azimuth': 164:54:12.6, 'set_time': 2015/10/9 23:45:39, 'set_azimuth': 343:53:08.6}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 17 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/10 01:16:53, 'max_alt': 14:03:31.7, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/10 01:19:24, 'rise_azimuth': 242:02:05.4, 'set_time': 2015/10/10 01:21:56, 'set_azimuth': 306:07:41.7}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 18 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/10 11:31:07, 'max_alt': 16:32:27.3, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/10 11:34:11, 'rise_azimuth': 48:01:28.1, 'set_time': 2015/10/10 11:37:15, 'set_azimuth': 127:20:19.7}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 19 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/10 13:07:48, 'max_alt': 83:09:23.6, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/10 13:12:39, 'rise_azimuth': 14:03:31.5, 'set_time': 2015/10/10 13:17:29, 'set_azimuth': 200:20:30.1}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 20 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/10 14:46:46, 'max_alt': 16:47:51.7, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/10 14:49:48, 'rise_azimuth': 346:18:53.3, 'set_time': 2015/10/10 14:52:50, 'set_azimuth': 268:16:04.5}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 21 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/10 22:43:06, 'max_alt': 36:47:48.6, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/10 22:47:28, 'rise_azimuth': 129:34:16.0, 'set_time': 2015/10/10 22:51:53, 'set_azimuth': 357:34:10.4}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 22 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/11 00:20:53, 'max_alt': 37:03:59.7, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/11 00:25:18, 'rise_azimuth': 195:12:03.6, 'set_time': 2015/10/11 00:29:47, 'set_azimuth': 331:13:22.2}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 23 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/11 12:14:30, 'max_alt': 36:23:39.9, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/11 12:18:59, 'rise_azimuth': 29:07:50.6, 'set_time': 2015/10/11 12:23:26, 'set_azimuth': 164:01:11.1}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 24 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/11 13:52:22, 'max_alt': 37:52:25.2, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/11 13:56:50, 'rise_azimuth': 2:51:43.8, 'set_time': 2015/10/11 14:01:16, 'set_azimuth': 229:20:06.2}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 25 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/11 21:51:35, 'max_alt': 16:19:41.3, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/11 21:54:31, 'rise_azimuth': 90:09:14.5, 'set_time': 2015/10/11 21:57:27, 'set_azimuth': 14:26:33.1}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 26 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/11 23:26:51, 'max_alt': 81:09:10.9, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/11 23:31:38, 'rise_azimuth': 158:45:08.8, 'set_time': 2015/10/11 23:36:28, 'set_azimuth': 346:17:49.7}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 27 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/12 01:07:00, 'max_alt': 16:47:21.3, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/12 01:10:05, 'rise_azimuth': 231:48:00.3, 'set_time': 2015/10/12 01:13:11, 'set_azimuth': 312:30:33.1}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 28 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/12 11:22:23, 'max_alt': 13:52:16.0, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/12 11:24:53, 'rise_azimuth': 54:26:46.6, 'set_time': 2015/10/12 11:27:22, 'set_azimuth': 117:03:52.0}
horizon:  10:00:00.0   passe[ 29 ]:  {'rise_time': 2015/10/12 12:58:37, 'max_alt': 83:24:53.9, 'max_alt_time': 2015/10/12 13:03:28, 'rise_azimuth': 16:27:45.1, 'set_time': 2015/10/12 13:08:19, 'set_azimuth': 194:13:19.5}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sebastien/PycharmProjects/drs/scripts/test_lib_orbi.py", line 179, in <module>
    test_ephem_horizon()
  File "C:/Users/Sebastien/PycharmProjects/drs/scripts/test_lib_orbi.py", line 159, in test_ephem_horizon
    passes.append(passListToDic(guy.next_pass(swisscube)))
  File "C:\Users\Sebastien\dev\drs\lib\site-packages\ephem\__init__.py", line 509, in next_pass
    return _libastro._next_pass(self, body)
ValueError: that satellite seems to stay always below your horizon
```

When I'm using a horizon of 10 degrees, it's functionning very well but if I'm using an horizon above 39 degrees, I have the following error:

> ValueError: that satellite seems to stay always below your horizon

But as you can see in results, we have many passes where the max altitude is above 45 degrees. So normaly I should have results with the satellite above the horizon of 45 degrees.

Why I got this error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The rising and setting routines in the old `libastro` that PyEphem uses are not terribly persistent — they make an initial attempt to find a highest altitude, but if the first culmination is too low to satisfy the conditions you have set, then they raise the error you are seeing. My guess is that the search routine is finding the first culmination in your list, where the max altitude is 11°, and then because this is less than 45° it is giving up and throwing the error.

If you want to see the algorithm in more detail to study its behavior, you can find it here:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/master/libastro-3.7.7/riset_cir.c#L160